# Can't draw bitmap as overlay

Tags: android, bitmap, draw

I'm trying to draw bitmap on my activity, showing button as overlay works like a charm, but I can't deal with bitmap. What should I change in my code?
I tried to manually call onDraw by mView.invalidate() in onCreate(), but it wouldn't work.
Thanks in advance!

```
package com.example.btserver

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HUD extends Service implements OnTouchListener {
    Button mButton;
    OverlayView mView;
    @Override
    public IBinder
    onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mView = new OverlayView(this);
        mButton = new Button(this);
        mButton.setText("Overlay button");
        mButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {   
                setText();
                return true;
            }
        });

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(

                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,//TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,//TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN, //will cover status bar as well!!!
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


        params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        params.y = 100;
        params.x = 100;
        params.setTitle("Load Average");
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(mButton, params);
        wm.addView(mView, params);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mButton != null)
        {
            ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mButton);
            mButton = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Overlay button event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }


    public void setText() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Overlay button event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

class OverlayView extends ViewGroup {
    private Paint mLoadPaint;

    Bitmap cursor;
    public int x = 0,y = 0;

    public void Update(int nx, int ny) {
        x = nx; y = ny;
    }

    public OverlayView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        cursor = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.cursor);

        mLoadPaint = new Paint();
        mLoadPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mLoadPaint.setTextSize(10);
        mLoadPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(cursor, 0,0, mLoadPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: onDraw is controlled by OS so you have no option to force the OS to call onDraw but yes you can request for onDraw but when system will execute depends on when UI thread is free